# Require JSON data in API request

Tags: rest, cakephp-3.0

I am working on RESTful API in `CakePHP 3` and I need to force that data and request `Content-Type` is `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add in your AppController.php  in the beforeFilter

```
public function beforeFilter(event $event) {
    $this->request->params['_ext'] = 'json';
}
```

That way you will treat every incomming request as it was done with the .json extension, That might set you of into the right direction